# Download VSTS Attachments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Has anybody figured out how retrieve attachment IDs and download WorkItem attachments from VSTS using the C# libraries? I've reviewed the [AttachmentsSample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/AttachmentsSample.cs) in the nuget repository, but that sample doesn't show how to get attachment IDs. It only uploads a file then turns around and downloads the same file. The C# API does not seem to be documented anywhere, and the VSTS REST API has not yielded anything useful. I'm about at my wits' end, here!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code sample to download attachments for work items:

Install the Nuget Package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

Just change the stored path for the attachments, in below sample the path is `D:\\temp\\vsts`

---

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace DownloadWITAttachments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com");
            string PAT = "nvxxxxxrdrtrxxxgghhjhvi3mia3yasldjfkoe353lew5pyywed";
            string project = "ProjectName";

            VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", PAT);

            //create a wiql object and build our query
            Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
            {
                Query = "Select * " +
                        "From WorkItems " +
                        "Where [Work Item Type] = 'User Story' " +
                        "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                        "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
                        "And [System.AttachedFileCount] > 0 " +
                        "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
            };

            //create instance of work item tracking http client
            using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
            {
                //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
                WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

                if (workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count() != 0)
                {
                    //Download the first attachment for each work item.
                    foreach (var item in workItemQueryResult.WorkItems)
                    {
                        TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri);
                        ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
                        WorkItemStore wistore = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem wi = wistore.GetWorkItem(item.Id);
                        WorkItemServer wiserver = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();                       
                        string tmppath = wiserver.DownloadFile(wi.Attachments[0].Id);
                        string filename = string.Format("D:\\temp\\vsts\\{0}-{1}", wi.Fields["ID"].Value, wi.Attachments[0].Name);
                        File.Copy(tmppath, filename);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matt Have you resolved the issue? Is the code working for you? any update?