# Download Attachments from TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, migration, azure-devops-rest-api

### Background

I am attempting to migrate from TFS to Gitlab, I am able to get the code and migrate work items over by exporting a query into an excel sheet. Then run a tool against that it generates the issues.

### Problem

Most of our work items have attachments like documents and images that were saved to the work item, I have attempted to follow the guides from mentioned below. We will be leaving TFS so if we don't get it then we will lose all attachments

- [Download VSTS Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077454/download-vsts-attachments)
- [Calling Team Foundation Server(TFS) APIs via SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57176987/calling-team-foundation-servertfs-apis-via-sql-server-stored-procedure)
- [How to update the query in TFS 2019 using C# VS2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382357/how-to-update-the-query-in-tfs-2019-using-c-sharp-vs2019)
- [Download workitem attachments from TFS (files corrupted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984056/download-workitem-attachments-from-tfs-files-corrupted)

### Question

Has anyone been able to migrate attachments? Or at the bare minimum a way to download all attachments locally?

## TL;DR

How can I download attachments programmatically from TFS?

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone been able to migrate attachments? Or at the bare minimum a
> way to download all attachments locally?

No sure how to migrate attachments to Gitlab. However, you can reference the following code to download all work item attachments locally (base on your work item query - WIQL).

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace DownloadWITAttachments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
            string PAT = "nvxxxxxrdrtrxxxgghhjhvi3mia3yasldjfkoe353lew5pyywed";
            string project = "ProjectName";

            VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", PAT);

            //create a wiql object and build our query
            Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
            {
                Query = "Select * " +
                        "From WorkItems " +
                        "Where [Work Item Type] = 'User Story' " +
                        "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                        "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
                        "And [System.AttachedFileCount] > 0 " +
                        "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
            };

            //create instance of work item tracking http client
            using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
            {
                //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
                WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

                if (workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count() != 0)
                {
                    //Download attachments for each work item.
                    foreach (var item in workItemQueryResult.WorkItems)
                    {
                        TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri);
                        ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
                        WorkItemStore wistore = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem wi = wistore.GetWorkItem(item.Id);
                        WorkItemServer wiserver = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();
                        
                        //Check each work item's attachment count, then download them in a loop
                        int atc = wi.Attachments.Count;
                            for (int i = 0; i < atc; i++)
                            {
                                string tmppath = wiserver.DownloadFile(wi.Attachments[i].Id);
                                string filename = string.Format("D:\\temp\\vsts\\{0}-{1}", wi.Fields["ID"].Value, wi.Attachments[i].Name);
                                File.Copy(tmppath, filename);
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\n", filename));
                           }      
                        Console.ReadLine();                     
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also try to call the REST API in a script to download the work item attachments from a project based on the work item query:

1. Create a work item query in you project to get all the Requirement work items which you want to down attachments from them.
   [image]
2. Write a script to call the REST API to get all the work items and the details, we can retrieve the attachment URLs from the details. After that we can call the [Attachments - Get REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#download-attachment)  in a loop to download all the work item attachments.
3. Below PowerShell script for your reference. Please change the parameters based on your project.

Below PowerShell script for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$project = "CMMI2",
   [string]$downloadlocation = "E:\Andy\0416\",
   [string]$QueryId = "d3606f18-1235-4151-8533-f347bf817925",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "xxx"
)


# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Query Work items by Query ID
$wisUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/wiql/$($QueryId)?api-version=6.0" 
$queryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wisUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$wits = $queryresult.workItems.id #| where({$_.fields.'System.WorkItemType' -eq 'Task'}) # Change the workitem type to filter differnet wits 
Write-host $wits


ForEach ($wi in $wits) 
{

#Get work item details 
$baseUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($wi)?api-version=6.0&"+"$"+"expand=all"
Write-Host $baseUrl         
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

#Write-Host ($response |ConvertTo-Json) 

#Get the attachments
$attachments = $response.relations | where({$_.rel -eq 'AttachedFile'}) 

#Write-Host $attachments.url

    ForEach ($attachment in $attachments) {
    $attachmentname = $attachment.attributes.name
    $attachmenturl = $attachment.url
    Write-Host $attachmentname

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $attachmenturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile $downloadlocation\$attachmentname

    }

}
```

If you want to download all attachments for a specific work item, then you can run the following script:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://<domain>/tfs/<_Collection>",
   [string]$project = "<project>",
   [string]$workitemid = "workitemid",  
   [string]$downloadlocation = "E:\xxx\xxx\",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "xxx"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get work item details 
$baseUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)?api-version=4.1&"+"$"+"expand=all"
Write-Host $baseUrl         
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

#Get the attachments
$attachments = $response.relations | where({$_.rel -eq 'AttachedFile'}) 

#Download the attachments in a loop
ForEach ($attachment in $attachments) {
$attachmentname = $attachment.attributes.name
$attachmenturl = $attachment.url
Write-Host $attachmentname

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $attachmenturl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile $downloadlocation\$attachmentname
}
```

Comment: I am running on Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 15.117.27414.0, so my url is setup uses the following URL 

https://<domain>/tfs/<_Collection>/<project>/_workitems?id=98851

Comment: But thank you so much for helping, if you had time could you help me clarify/figure out what API version I would need to use/abstract my previous comment.

Comment: @B.Cratty You are using TFS 2017, please use the API version 4.1 or 5.0. See [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) and [Attachments - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#download-attachment). Since we are using the GET method in the script, actually we can also try to remove the `api-version=x` from the URL, It will automatically match the appropriate api version when calling the API.

Comment: @B.Cratty BTW, If you want to download all attachments for a specific work item, then please see my updated answer (the last paragraph).

Answer (score -1):

You can download all of the attachments for the work items of the TFS if you are using Visual Studio.

Steps-
Launch Visual Studio, choose your TFS project and then click "home" in the TEAM EXPLORER right-hand column.

Now choose work items from the options and put the work item number in the team explorer's search field OF VISUAL STUDIO. The work item will then appear in a new window once you press the Enter key.

In addition to the link choice, you can choose the attachments option. Simply select the first attachment and press Ctrl+A to select them all, and then press SAVE COPY to save them to a folder.